# Does a bivariate c.d.f. have this property?

Tags: probability, functions, probability-distributions

Let $F(\cdot,\cdot)$ denote the c.d.f. of a bivariate random vector with the support $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Suppose that for some constants $\delta_1>0, \Delta_1>0$ and $\delta_2>0, \Delta_2>0$ such that $\delta_1\geq\Delta_1$ and $\delta_2\leq\Delta_2$ it holds that 
$$F(z_1+\Delta_1,z_2+\Delta_2) - F(z_1,z_2+\Delta_2) -F(z_1+\Delta_1,z_2)+F(z_1,z_2) = \\  F(z_1+\delta_1,z_2+\delta_2) - F(z_1,z_2+\delta_2) -F(z_1+\delta_1,z_2)+F(z_1,z_2) $$
for all $(z_1,z_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Does it necessarily imply that $\delta_1=\Delta_1$ and $\delta_2=\Delta_2$ regardless of the specific form of the c.d.f. $F(\cdot,\cdot)$? I am happy to impose additional properties on $F$ if this would help.

I think I can establish this property when the support of the random vector is bounded but ultimately I am interested in the general case.

Comment: That looks dubious to me: the quantity $F(z_1+h, z_2+k)-F(z_1+h,z_2)-F(z_1,z_2+k)+F(z_1,z_2)$ is real and depends on two variables $k$ and $h$. i would expect, typically, its level sets to be $1$-dimensional.

Comment: Due to the geometry of the problem (this quantity is the integral of $\Delta F$ on a rectangle), I don't see how the restrictions on $h$ and $k$ would give anything more. How would you prove it when the random vector is bounded? Isn't it false for the CDF of $\delta_{(0,0)}$?

Comment: I think it's easy to come up with a counter-example. The quantity $F(z_1+\Delta_1,z_2+\Delta_2) - F(z_1,z_2+\Delta_2) -F(z_1+\Delta_1,z_2)+F(z_1,z_2) $ is sometimes known as the [H-volume](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252525/does-anyone-know-what-the-intuition-of-h-volume-is). Imagine a distribution that is symmetric for the interchange of $z_1$ and $z_2$. Then imagine that $\delta_2=\Delta_1 < \Delta_2=\delta_1$ and $z_1=z_2$. Then the H-volumes should be equal.

Comment: @D.Thomine I was thinking is the support is bounded and, say, $\delta_1>\Delta_1$, then I can choose $z_1$ in such a way that $z_1$ and $z_1+\Delta_1$ are outside of the support whereas $z_1+\delta_1$ is inside the support, giving a contradiction. I think this should work for a rectangular bounded support.

Comment: @Raskolnikov I don't think it is a counterexample. The equality should hold not only for $z_1=z_2$ but for any $(z_1,z_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I glanced over that part.

Answer (score 1):

This visual argument isn't a complete proof but perhaps a step in the right direction.

Visually, the condition
$$
F(z_1+\Delta_1,z_2+\Delta_2)-F(z_1,z_2+\Delta_2)-F(z_1+\Delta_1,z_2)+F(z_1,z_2)=\\F(z_1+\delta_1,z_2+\delta_2)-F(z_1,z_2+\delta_2)-F(z_1+\delta_1,\delta_2)+F(z_1,z_2)
$$

corresponds to the diagram below where the blue rectangle and the orange rectangle have to contain equal probability mass.

[image: Visual representation of cumulative distribution condition]

Since the two rectangles always overlap in this way when $\delta_1 \ge \Delta_1$ and $\delta_2 \le \Delta_2$, we know that the two rectangles below (modified from the two above) have to contain equal probability mass since we just removed the shared rectangle.

[image: Cumulative distribution condition with shared rectangle removed]

We now show that
\begin{equation}
(\delta_1 - 2\Delta_1)(\Delta_2-2\delta_2) > 0 \qquad... (1)
\end{equation}

We demonstrate the basic proof by contradiction using $\delta_1 = 2\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2 = 2\delta_2$, which does not satisfy (1) above.

[image: ₁ = 2Δ₁ and Δ₂ = 2₂]

Note that the two rectangles have the same area as well as containing the same probability mass. If we shift this diagram up and left and superimpose it on itself, we get the figure below. This operation corresponds to considering the original constraint for $z_1' = z_1-\Delta_1$ and $z_2' = z_2+\delta_2$.

[image: ₁ = 2Δ₁ and Δ₂ = 2₂ with replication]

This figure shows that the probability mass contained in region $A$ equals that contained in regions $B$ and $C$. However since each of these regions contains positive probability mass (since the distribution has support on $\mathbb{R}^2$), and since we can repeat this replication process indefinitely, this means the total probability mass of the sum of all these regions would scale without bound. This is impossible since the total probability mass of a distribution is 1. We conclude that ($\delta_1 = 2\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2 = 2\delta_2$) is impossible.

A similar argument holds for each of the figures below. In each case either $P(A) > P(B) > P(C)$ or $P(A) < P(B) < P(C)$, which means the amount of probability mass in these equal-area regions grows without bound as we replicate the figure either up-and-left or down-and-right.

[image: ₁ ≥ 2Δ₁ and Δ₂ ≤ 2₂ with replication]

[image: ₁ ≤ 2Δ₁ and Δ₂ ≥ 2₂ with replication]

This argument does not work when (1) holds since we get the following replication diagram where the blue and orange rectangles are not subsets of each other in either direction.

[image: ₁ > 2Δ₁ and Δ₂ > 2₂ with replication]

I'm not yet sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Thank you, i was thinking visually along similar lines. The case of a rectangular  support is a special case of this -- when a mass completely disappears after some threshold. It is indeed a helpful start. Even though it is not a complete answer, i am happy to award the bounty (if i still can).

Comment: I am trying to work out whether there is something useful one can do to manipulate the overlapping orange and blue rectangles in the final figure above but no luck so far. My intuition is that the infinite replication of rectangles trick should help with proving that all cases lead to a contradiction somehow.

Comment: I tried constructing bands which would have their probabilities expressed in terms of marginal distributions and tried getting a contradiction but hasn't quite worked yet